# Rails check_box does not hold data needed to update the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view which contains a form which is used to create a model.
My code worked fine until I added an attribute to the model which is obtained using a checkbox.
Now, my code fails, as `debate_type` is not updated and therefore the model is not created:

The code I've added which prevents the creation of the model:

Model:

```
  validates_presence_of :debate_type
```

View:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :debate_type, {}, "technical", "management" %>
    <%= f.label :debate_type, "technical" %>
  </div>
```

I am not sure why the attribute `debate_type` is not updated.

Comment: Could you provide your controller action code?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, I forgot to permit the `debate_type` parameter.

```
def subject_params
  params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :body, :parent_id, :debate_type)
end
```